# Magento 2 getIsDeveloperMode

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to determine the mode programatically. What is the Magento 2 equivalent to **`Mage::getIsDeveloperMode()`** ? Or, how do I get **MAGE_MODE** from env.php?

Comment: Where you want to use and why?

Comment: please find this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151367/get-magento-2-mode-programatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your purpose you can use the `DeploymentConfig` class:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig
 */
protected $deploymentConfig;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig $deploymentConfig
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig $deploymentConfig
) {
    $this->deploymentConfig = $deploymentConfig;
}

public function getMageMode()
{
    return $this->deploymentConfig->get('MAGE_MODE'); 
    // returns the mage mode from the app/etc/env.php
}
```

Comment: I don't have the getMageMode function in DeploymentConfig. But, there is a generic get() function that works. ie. ->get('MAGE_MODE')

Answer (score 1):

You can read the env.php and get the config value you want. Look into the below magento core class

```
vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig/Reader.php
```

Check the function **loadConfigFile**

```
if ($fileDriver->isExists($path . '/' . $pathConfig)) {
    $configResult = include $path . '/' . $pathConfig;
    if (is_array($configResult)) {
        $result = array_replace_recursive($result, $configResult);
    }
}
```

This will return you array in env.php and you can use that to fetch value of `MAGE_MODE`. You can simply inject the above class and call the method `loadConfigFile`.